# excel vba: sheet name as variable

Tags: vba

I am trying to select a sheet based on the variable. I could successfully rename the sheet with variable sname but could not activate the same

```
Dim sname as String
sname = Trim(Cells(row, 12).Value)
Sheets("Blank (2)").name = sname
Sheets(sname).Activate
Sheets(sname).Select
```

Comment: works for me. what error do you get?

Comment: I get the error 'subscript out of range'

Comment: Why would you need to `.Activate` and `.Select` the sheet anyway?

Comment: subscript out of range in this case would mean the sheet doesn't exist. sure it's right? sure you've got the right workbook open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying this works?

> ```
> Sheets("Blank (2)").name = sname
> ```

Then, do this:

```
With Sheets("Blank (2)")
    .Name = sname
    .Activate
    .Select
End With
```

The idea is to grab a reference to the worksheet you're working with, instead of constantly fetching the object from the `Sheets` collection every time.

Alternatively:

```
Dim target As Worksheet
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blank (2)")
target.Name = sname
target.Activate
target.Select
```

Note that the `Sheets` collection, unqualified as you've used it, implicitly refers to the active workbook. Assuming that active workbook is the same workbook the code is written in, it's best to qualify the call with `ThisWorkbook`, and to use the `Worksheets` collection instead - because the `Sheets` collection can contain non-worksheet objects (e.g. charts).

Lastly, I doubt there's any need to `.Select` anything here. Read more about avoiding `.Select` and `.Activate` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513).