# How to enter a formula in a cell that references the sheet name from a string variable?

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA enters a formula in a cell. This formula references another sheet.

I'd like to replace the sheet name '13) Friends Mailer' with a string variable, so the formula references a sheet of my choosing.

```vb
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'13) Friends Mailer'!R6C1:R90C15,14,0)+VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'13) Friends Mailer'!R6C1:R90C15,15,0)"
```

I tried:

```vb
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'" &worksheetName& "'!R[4]C[-9]:R[88]C[5],14,0)+VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'13) Friends Mailer'!R[4]C[-9]:R[88]C[5],15,0)"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use string value from a cell to access worksheet of same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899175/use-string-value-from-a-cell-to-access-worksheet-of-same-name)

Comment: Also a better possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456960/excel-vba-sheet-name-as-variable

Comment: I might sound a little redicolous, but is `worksheetName` a `String` or a `Worksheet`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'" &worksheetName&
```

with:

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'" & worksheetName &
```

*(there may be other problems)*

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = "13) Friends Mailer"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'" & txt & "'!R6C1:R90C15,14,0)+VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'" & txt & "'!R6C1:R90C15,15,0)"
```